# Another SelectedIndexChanged PostBack Resetting Index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I really hate asking since there are so many similar issues related to SelectedIndexChanged not firing.  However, I can't figure this one out.  Here is my DDL:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPart1Country" 
CssClass="form-control" 
AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPart1Country_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

I have a master page setting EnableViewState="True", and it also has my ScriptManager and form element.  Really, nothing out of the ordinary here.  With it like this the SelectedIndexChanged will fire just fine.  My problem comes in when wrapped by any other element, (e.g.:  Panel, div, etc.)  My DDL will fire a PostBack, but the index doesn't change, therefore not firing the SelectedIndexChanged event.

So, it will not change the index when for instance:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddlPart1Country" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Country<i class="required"></i></label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPart1Country" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPart1Country_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Identical DDL control, the only difference is its placement in the div.

And here is my codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        FillPart1Countries();
}

protected void FillPart1Countries()
{
    var lstOptions = CacheValues.Countries;

    if (lstOptions == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ddlPart1Country.Items.Add(new ListItem(" -- Select Your Country -- ", ""));
    foreach (var option in lstOptions.Result)
    {
        ddlPart1Country.Items.Add(new ListItem(option.Ctry, option.GENC0));
    }
}
protected void ddlPart1Country_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlPart1Country.SelectedItem.Value == "")
        return;

    var lstOptions = FormPopulation.GetStatesAndProvences(ddlPart1Country.SelectedItem.Value);



    ddlPart1StateOrProvence.Items.Clear();
    ddlPart1StateOrProvence.Items.Add(new ListItem(" -- Select Your State/Provence -- ", ""));
    foreach (var option in lstOptions.Result)
    {
        ddlPart1StateOrProvence.Items.Add(new ListItem(option.Name, option.GENC1));
    }

    lblCountrySelected.Text = ddlPart1Country.SelectedItem.Text;
    upnlPart1State.Update();

}
```

I'm not rebuilding the DDL on PostBack.  ViewState is enabled.  I know it has to be something dumb I'm doing or not doing, but I can't see it.  What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure it s not firing? try putting a breakpoint at the very beginning of `page_load` and change the DDL index, see if it gets into the load function first.

Comment: Not that this is the problem, but is that your complete code behind?  I don't see ddlPart1Country_SelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: I am sure it is not firing because I do set a breakpoint on Page_Load and it works outside the <div>.  And sorry, I did forget the ddlPart1Country_SelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this, I think I may have fixed something like this a while ago by switching the `<div>` to `<asp:Panel>`.  I'm not sure what the problem was, though, since it normally works fine.

Comment: Could something in the css class be throwing it off?

Comment: it was a good idea to test without my CSS.  However, it didn't change anything.  But while I was at it, I thought I would try without my scripts as well.  Wouldn't you know it, I have a client-side form validator that renames the ASP-generated "name" attributes to the ID="..." values.  Removing that line solved it.  Thanks for that idea!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steve's idea about CSS, I removed the script libraries I was using, too.  One of them is for my client-side validation and there was a line there:

```
$.each($('div').children(), function() {
    $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

That forces the DOM to rename the name attribute to the ID of the ASP control. Removing that of course solved the issue. That's what I get for using a hack for client-side validation in the first place.  Thanks to everyone that gave this a look.